# Using dnsmasq in a Docker container for the host and for Docker internal DNS resolution

Tags: networking, docker, docker-compose, dnsmasq

I'm working on a web project that consists of multiple services. Every service has it's own docker-compose.yml file that declares it's "app" and it's possible dependencies (databases etc). To have them all play nicely together, I have built a local dev env that ties them together with an nginx proxy that has server blocks with proper servernames and then proxy_pass'es the requests to the actual containers using Docker's networking.

I've also added dnsmasq in a container as well to aid with DNS, to use the domain names locally instead of localhost:port combo's (by adding a resolver for the test tld to 127.0.0.1).

Proxy docker-compose:

```
services:
    local-proxy:
        build: ./nginx
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443

    local-proxy-dnsmasq:
        build: ./dnsmasq # builds on top of 4km3/dnsmasq
        ports:
            - "53:53/tcp"
            - "53:53/udp"
        cap_add:
            - NET_ADMIN
networks:
    default:
        external:
            name: domain-local
```

dnsmasq.conf:

```
listen-address=0.0.0.0
interface=eth0
user=root

address=/.test/0.0.0.0
```

example proxy nginx server:

```
server {
    server_name login.domain.test;
    location / {
        # headers...
        proxy_pass http://domain-login:8080;
    }
}
```

example docker-compose of one of the services:

```
services:
    domain-login:
        build: # ...
        networks:
            - default
            - domain-local
```

All of this works perfectly fine in the browser, I can go to `tenant.domain.test` , get redirected to `login.domain.test`...

However, when the container running tenant.domain.test has to make a curl request from it's container to one of the others (e.g. login.domain.test to complete the oauth flow), it borks as it's trying to resolve `login.domain.test` by going to itself:

```
root@6d25c2f5daf1:/var/www/app# nslookup login.domain.test
Server:     127.0.0.11
Address:    127.0.0.11#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   login.domain.test
Address: 0.0.0.0
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

If I change the dnsmasq.conf from `address=/.test/0.0.0.0` to `address=/.test/10.0.1.102` (the currently assigned IP of my computer), everything works. However this is of course not a working solution for coworkers for example. Can anyone set me on the correct Google path potentially or have a fix?

Answer (score 1):

The line `address=/.test/0.0.0.0` tells `dnsmasq` to resolve domain name `test` to IP address `0.0.0.0`. The address `0.0.0.0` is [not a valid IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0). It is handled by some browsers (e.g. chrome) as `127.0.0.1` but it is non-standard behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

just came across this and wanted to give a quick answer.
Because OP said

> working solution for coworkers for example

I understood the OP wants a shareable ip, which could be from the office network of course. (Just do an `ifconfig` or whatever to get your com ip and assign that with dnsmasq ;p)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/574237)